# Add SQL-feature with what Servicepack

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I need to add an SQL-feature (SQL-replication) to an existing SQL-instance. It's SQL Server 2012 Standard SP1 that has been upgraded to SP3 a few years ago.

What installation media should I use to add the SQL-feature?

SQL Server 2012 Std  with SP1 or SQL Server 2012 Std with SP3?

Or can I add it by installing the SP3 again somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a recommendation from an SQL-expert that I really should use the SQL Server 2012 Std with SP3.

And it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a feature with the base media for 2012 Standard by running setup and choosing that feature, then, once it completes, you can run the Service Pack install and/or cumulative updates to get it to the current level of the features and engine installed.